# vue.js - Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: vue.js

I am filtering projects with a computed property like this:

```
filtered_projects() {
    return this.projects.filter( (project)  =>  {
        return project.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.project_filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    })
}
```

When I add a new project using this

```
submitNewProject() {
   let path = '/api/projects';
   Vue.http.post(path, this.project)
       .then( (rsp) => {
          this.projects.push(rsp.data);
          this.project = this.getSingleProject();
          this.create_project = false;
          return true;
    });
 }
```

This is giving me an error that I can't find

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be that you are not correctly passing the projects data to the projects array.

Firstly vue-resource now uses `body` not data to get the response, therefore you may need to use:

```
this.projects.push(rsp.body)
```

then this will give you a single array item containing all projects which doesn't look like what you want. I believe instead you're after:

```
this.projects = rsp.body
```

Assuming the response body is an array of objects this will then allow:

```
this.projects.filter(project => {})
```

to work as expected. Meaning `project.title` should now be valid

**EDIT**

For a project title to be set to lowerCase you must be returning an object with a title param, i.e.

```
rsp.body = {
  title: 'FOO',
}
```

which you'd then set on the projects array via:

```
this.projects.push(rsp.body)
```

so the first thing to fix is your response, sort your endpoint so it returns what you are expecting, then the rest of the above code should work

Comment: this.projects.push(rsp.body) didn't change the error.

Comment: this.projects = rsp.body created a new error "TypeError: this.projects.filter is not a function"

Comment: what does the response look like? Is it an object or array or objects?

Comment: yeah `.filter` will only work against an array - is this what you have?

Comment: can you post the response content

Comment: Response
body
:
8
bodyBlob
:
Blob
bodyText
:
PromiseObj
data
:
8
get data
:
()
set data
:
(body)
headers
:
Headers
ok
:
true
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
url
:
"/api/projects"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: I was hoping you'd just show me an object :) but assuming that's what it is perhaps the endpoint isn't passing it as json, but instead text, try and convert the response before pushing to the array, i.e. `this.projects.push(rsp.json())`

Comment: that'll be your problem then - you're returning an integer not an object. Updated answer to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

You need preserve "this" before Vue.http.post (self=this) and then in callback change this.projects to self.projects.
Explanation:
[How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: I thought the => syntax changed that